# Clipping image to an svg

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, clip

Is there a way to clip an image to an SVG shape with a `CanvasRenderingContext2D`?
I'm trying to use different SVG shapes to display various parts of an image on demand.

For example – an SVG with an `<ellipse>` element (or an equivalent `<path>`) would allow me to show a circular portion of the image.

[CanvasRenderingContext2D.clip()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clip) seems to be the close to what I need, but I can't find any information about how to use it with an SVG, or alternatively how to draw an SVG as a path.

Another direction I'm thinking about is saving the clipping area as a `<path>` element and manually transforming it to `CanvasRenderingContext2D` equivalent methods such as `lineTo` and `arc`.

Comment: svg images when rendered on canvas become raster and loose all vector informations. Two way I can think of to do what you want : parse your svg first and then use the canvas API to draw those shapes (path commands are quite similar so it's not so hard and library like fabricjs can even handle it in a nice way for you) or use globalCompositeOperation instead of clipping. But note that for the later, Firefox has a bug in applying gCO directly to an svg image, which force you to first draw your svg on a second canvas ; and that IE prior to Edge will taint the canvas when an svg is drawn to it.

Answer (score 1):

@Kaiido has some good suggestions for you (see his comment to the question).

- Draw the SVG to canvas & use globalCompositeOperation instead of clipping.  But Firefox has a bug in applying gCO directly to an svg image, which force you to first draw your svg on a second canvas ; and that IE prior to Edge will taint the canvas when an svg is drawn to it.
- Parse your svg first and then use the canvas API to draw those shapes (path commands are quite similar so it's not so hard and library like fabricjs can even handle it in a nice way for you)

Another option is to convert your SVG drawings to .png format and use that image + globalCompositeOperation to clip your image inside the .png shape. This avoids the cross-browser problems with SVG.

But, if your clipping shapes are just simple SVG paths (ovals, etc), then you might forget SVG and draw your path using canvas path commands.

[image][image]

I'll repost a previous SO [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33898822/clip-an-image-to-form-an-oval-centered-image/33905110#33905110) to illustrate clipping inside a canvas path:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/kidwallpaper.jpg";
function start(){

  // resize the canvas to equal the image size
  var iw=img.width;
  var ih=img.height;
  cw=canvas.width=iw;
  ch=canvas.height=ih;

  // calculate the scaling needed to max the display of the image
  // inside the oval
  if(iw>ih){
    var scaleX=iw/ih
    var scaleY=1;
    var r=ih/2;
  }else{
    var scaleX=1;
    var scaleY=ih/iw;
    var r=iw/2;
  }

  // scale so the circle (arc) becomes an oval
  ctx.scale(scaleX,scaleY);
  ctx.arc(cw/scaleX/2,ch/scaleY/2,r,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fill();

  // undo the scaling
  ctx.scale(1/scaleX,1/scaleY);

  // draw the image centered inside the oval using compositing
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
  ctx.drawImage(img,cw/2-img.width/2,ch/2-img.height/2);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: black; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Three steps:

1. Draw the SVG to your canvas.
2. Set `context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';`
3. Draw the image.

The image will only be drawn where the SVG has already filled in pixels with colour, effectively clipping the image to whatever has already been drawn.

You can either set the `globalCompositeOperation` back to `'source-over'` (the default), or use `context.save()` before and `context.restore()` after to put the canvas back into a "normal" drawing mode.

Comment: That's a one shot clipping.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly. You can:

- Draw the SVG into a canvas and use that for compositing to clip. Drawback is that some browsers has limited support due to security (external links, tainting the canvas and so on).
- Parse the SVG manually

Here is an example of how you can build a simple parser for SVG. It cannot be used for generic use but assumes you know the SVG in question. You can build on top of this to support different units, transform lists etc.

The path that is extracted can be stored on a Path2D object instead of directly as shown below (Path2D may need [poly-fill](https://github.com/google/canvas-5-polyfill) in some browsers), or store custom objects/arrays etc. This is entirely up to you.

The example is more a proof-of-concept.

### Example SVG parser to canvas Path2D

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    mask = document.getElementById("mask");  // get a SVG element

// some random graphics
for(var i=30,r=Math.random;i--;) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + (360*r()) + ",50%,50%)";ctx.fillRect(280*r(),120*r(),50,50)}

// parse SVG element
if (mask.localName) {
  switch(mask.localName) {
    case "rect":
      ctx.rect(v("x"), v("y"), v("width"), v("height"));
      break;
    case "ellipse":
      // need polyfill in some browsers
      ctx.ellipse(v("cx"), v("cy"), v("rx"), v("ry"), 0, 6.28);
      break;
    // more cases here
  }

  // use path from SVG to clip
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
  ctx.fill();
}

// helper - obtains a numeric value for SVG element property
function v(name) {return mask[name].baseVal.value}
```

```css
#c, svg {border:1px solid #777}
```

```html
<h4>SVG (showing mask)</h4>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     width="300" height="150">
  <rect id="mask" x="50" y="30" width="200" height="100" />
</svg>

<h4>Canvas (mask applied from SVG)</h4>
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```